# How to build 64 bit python from source on solaris

Tags: python, gcc, x86-64

I am trying to build python 64 bit from source on solaris10.
After searching in net for a while. I tried using CFLAGS=-m64 LDFLAGS=-m64 while executing ./configure.But getting errors like wrong ELFCLASS32

Tried the below

./configure  CFLAGS=-m64 LDFLAGS=-m64
But no luck. And make is throwing errror like  "make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `libinstall'"

I am suspecting this is regarding gcc

TIA

Comment: using a 64 bit compiler would help. I think you wouldn't need the -m64 flags, then

Comment: This is more of a "please solve some task for me" request than a programming question, so it's not entirely the proper place to ask. In any case, find some Python distributions for Solaris and then find out how those were built. Also, make sure you checked the bugtickets at bugs.python.org (if Solaris is a supported architecture in the first place). If none of this helps, turn the task into a programming question by extracting a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are linking your 64-bit program with 32-bit libraries. That is what the WRONGELFCLASS error is all about.

Unfortunately, the default on Solaris tends to be to generate 32-bit libraries. Make sure you generate 64-bit libraries with `-m64` and use the `file` command on the generated `.o` files to verify they are 64-bit libraries.  The 64-bit libraries are in subdirectory `64/` for each library directory (such as `/usr/lib/64/`).